# How to count the appearance of the values after using .value_counts()?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df:

```
name | col1 | col2
A    | xx   | 123
B    | yy   | 123
C    | xx   | 87
A    | jk   | 10
A    | j7   | k
B    | mm   | 9
D    | xx   | ki
D    | kl   | 90
E    | k    | 17
```

I want to count how often each name appears in the column "name", then I want to count how often each value appears.

So

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
{
    "name": ["A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "B", "D", "D", "E"],
    "col1": ["xx", "yy", "xx", "jk", "j7", "mm", "xx", "kl", "k"],
    "col": ["123", "123", "87", "10", "k", "9", "ki", "90", "17"],
})

df = df["name"].value_counts()
```

Result:

```
A    3
D    2
B    2
C    1
E    1
```

But I need to count how often each "value_count()" value appears (3 appears only 1x, 2 appears 2x, 1 appears 2x). The end result should look like this:

```
3    1
2    2
1    2
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Chain another `.value_counts()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps just simply chain another `.value_counts()`:

```
df["name"].value_counts().value_counts()
```